# in CMSIS, why are bitfield positions 'unsigned int' but the mask base 'unsigned long int'?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, cortex-m, cmsis

Here is an example from a ST CMSIS header:

```
#define USART_ISR_TC_Pos              (6U)
#define USART_ISR_TC_Msk              (0x1UL << USART_ISR_TC_Pos)
```

Everywhere in CMSIS headers, the bitfield positions (`_Pos`) are given as decimal integer constants of type `unsigned int` and the unshifted masks are `unsigned long int`.

Why is it that they both are not specified as `unsigned long int`?

Comment: Probably because if you are working with 64bit system, the position is within 0..63 which fits `unsigned int` range while the result of `<<` may overflow the range of `unsigned int`, thus it should be `UL` (which can be 32 bits or 64 bits, based on the system).

Comment: The right of `<<` is just the number of bits to shift, which humans prefer as decimal ("the 4th bit"). But you can do it in any base (octal, hex). Of course this should be a positive number.

Comment: `unsigned int` is required to be able to hold 2^16 as a minimum. It might be a bit short sighted but I cannot imagine a machine where this is not sufficient to describe the number of bits in an `unsigned long`. And using any value larger than the number of bits in a shift operation would cause undefined behaviour anyway. Therefore even an `unsigned char` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bit position: Position in the register cannot be more than 31 and **any** integer type in C can hold it. There is no reason even to make the position unsigned.
2. The **mask**. As the minimum `unsigned int` size required by the C standard is not big enough to hold 32 bit value, It has to be declared as unsigned long. CMSIS authors do not know the compiler you are going to use so they use the **minimal** sufficient type.

Answer (score 0):

There's no apparent reason why. I very much doubt these libs are meant to be shared with 8- or 16 bitters, which would be the only sensible explanation.

A Cortex M will be 32 bit with 32 bit `int` and 32 bit `long`. And most importantly 32 bit hardware peripheral registers. So even if `long` was 64 bit it would be senseless to shift a mask outside the register bounds.

The `U` suffix is enough to prevent undefined behavior left shifts on a signed operand. Other sloppy libs use the bugged `1 << n` style, so maybe `1UL` was a quick fix to correct that bug - where `1U` would have worked just as fine.